# Haskell Accelerate replicate matrix

Tags: haskell, accelerate-haskell

How can I replicate matrix in Haskell Accelerate?
For example, I have a matrix `mat :: Matrix (Z :. 2 :. 5) ...`. I want to get a three-dimensional array with shape `Z :. 9 :. 2 :. 5`.
I tried to use `A.replicate (A.lift (Z :. 9 :. All)) mat`, but I get an error

> Couldn't match type ‘Z’ with ‘DIM0 :. Int’
> Expected type: Acc (Array (SliceShape ((Z :. Int) :. All)) a)
> Actual type: Acc (Matrix a)

What does that mean?

And similarly, if I have a matrix with shape `Z :. 9 :. 5`, how can I get a three-dimensional array with shape `Z :. 9 :. 2 :. 5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the slice needs to have the same rank (number of dimensions) as the input array. `All` does not mean 'all the rest of the dimensions', but it only means 'all the elements in this dimension'. So you can solve your issue with:

```hs
A.replicate (A.lift (Z :. 9 :. All :. All)) mat
```

This also gives some intuition about how you might answer your second question:

```hs
A.replicate (A.lift (Z :. All :. 2 :. All)) mat
```

I don't know if there is a way to say 'all the rest of the dimensions'.

The error message `Couldn't match type 'Z' with 'DIM0 :. Int'` means that the rank of your shape is not correct. You need to add another dimension. Maybe it would be easier to read if it said: `Couldn't match type 'Z' with 'Z :. Int'`.